# PHP resources optimization for multiple small requests

Tags: php, mysql

*MYSQL structure:* multiple databases having the **same tables** in each database in the format:

db1.a 
db1.b 
...   
db2.a 
db2.b 
... 

.... 
....  and so on

*PHP structure:* 
./includes/  -->   files containing constants 
./work/     -->    files for interaction with db 
main.php   -->     check type of request and call function in file inside work folder

This system will be accessed by Android HTTP request and response queries using JSON and return data from the database in same manner.
The code for servicing the request will remain same only the db will change according to the user.

The crux of the matter is that - Thousands of users will send requests from Android app to any one function which interacts with only 1 the tables of a particular db in a single request. Essentially the code to be executed in each request will be very small with at-most 2 or 3 db queries per request.

I have a feeling that my solution is wrong at some level. There must be some way to optimize so many requests.

1. I will be including multiple include files containing array constants for each request. Will this lead to delay in response? I am currently including the files, creating objects of classes containing the constants and passing to whichever function it is required. Will keeping include objects in memcached be faster? Any other method to keep the objects in memory for all requests.
   Note: If i keep the include constants as static, code becomes more complex as I have to declare them global inside each function, which will be very cumbersome to deal with later on.
2. I read about people using some framework or the other - zend, symphony. What is the advantage of using such a framework and is it necessary for me to use any one of them?
3. Is there a way to keep the objects and db connection a session so that within a given timeframe if the same user with the same session id makes a request every php resource is re-used?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem very confused. Why is it important for us to know, that you got a folder named "work"? Try to be as precise as possible - maybe you see the solution then also by yourself.

To answer your questions:

1. There must be some way to optimize so many requests.
   When there are so many requests, I guess they will often get the same result. So you can cache your page.
2. this will result in just a minimal delay. It is so minimal you won't notice it ;)
3. The bigger your project is the better it is to use a framework. It simplifies many tasks and helps you to structure your project. It has a performance impact.
4. Yes there is a way to serialize objects. But since writing and reading the data can be slow too (and introduces maybe new software bugs) you should only do it for really big things. You can't/don't need to cache the mysql connection. When you use PDO or mysqli it is done automatically for you.

If you are a beginner you should stop worrying so much about performance and worry more about the quality of your code/architecture.. this helps more in the long run.
If you have to make a decision performance vs readability - always prefer the readability :)

Good luck with your project